# Good practice for Android services?

Tags: android

I want to create an independent service of my main activity. This service is started at boot my phone and retrieves information via webservice every x minutes.

What are the best practices to do this?

Launch a service with BOOT_COMPLETED action?

There he other actions to launch a service without launching the main activity?
Another design or best practice?

I want a service with the same behavior as Facebook for example. This service is active all the time and displays a notification when you receive a message. If you click on the notification, it opens the Facebook application. But that kills the application, served remains active for receiving new messages.

My first test kills my service when I want to kill my main activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="fr.mrbmx"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
    Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="fr.mr.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="fr.mr.service.MyReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="OnBootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service 
        android:name="fr.mr.service.LocalService" 
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="LocalService" />

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="@string/mapKey"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>
```

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = MyReceiver.class.getName();

@Override
public void onReceive( Context ctx, Intent i ) {
    Log.d( TAG, "MyReceiver.onReceive : " + i.getAction() );

    ctx.startService(new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName(
            ctx.getPackageName(), LocalService.class.getName())));
}
}




public class LocalService extends Service{

private static final String TAG = LocalService.class.getName();
private NotificationManager mNM;
// Unique Identification Number for the Notification.
    // We use it on Notification start, and to cancel it.
    private int NOTIFICATION = 1332;
    private Timer timer ;    
    private int mId;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
        mNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        timer = new Timer(); 

        Notification note = new Notification( 0, null, System.currentTimeMillis() );
        note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        startForeground( 0, note );
        /*
        Notification.Builder mBuilder =
                new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                .setContentTitle("test title")
                .setContentText("test content")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));


        startForeground(1, mBuilder.getNotification());*/
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);
        mId = startId;

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                    public void run() {
                        showNotification();
                    }
                }, 0, 60000); 

            }
        }).start();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy");
        mNM.cancel(NOTIFICATION);
    }


    /**
     * Show a notification while this service is running.
     */
    private void showNotification() {

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                .setContentTitle(getString(fr.mrbmx.R.string.notification_title))
                .setContentText(getString(fr.mrbmx.R.string.notification_text))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
        // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
        // started Activity.
        // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
        // your application to the Home screen.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
        mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your service does not need to be active all the time to receive messages. Facebook, along with just about every other push based system, use [Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) to wake up your device and send a message to your application from the remote server.

Of course, if you only need to periodically check (rather than be pushed information in near real time), then you can [schedule an alarm](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) to start your service every X minutes or build a [Sync Adapter](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html) - an Android component specifically built to [periodically load data](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/running-sync-adapter.html#RunPeriodic) from a remote server.

Note that many applications combine the two approaches and [run a sync adapter in response to a GCM push](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/running-sync-adapter.html#RunByMessage).

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create an independent service of my main activity. This
>   service is started at boot my phone and retrieves information via
>   webservice every x minutes.

You can certainly do this by registering a `BroadcastReceiver` on your `AndroidManifest.xml` that responds to `BOOT_COMPLETED` and launch the `Service` from it. Your app will need to be ran at least once for `BOOT_COMPLETED` to be delivered (before API 11 it wasn't the case). Also, consider the implications of pulling data from a server too often (i.e. battery, etc).

> I want a service with the same behavior as facebook for example. This
>   service is active all the time and displays a notification when you
>   receive a message. If you click on the nitification, it opens the
>   facebook application. But that kills the application, served remains
>   active for receiving new messages.

At least for their chat application, Facebook uses MQTT, which is a M2M publish/subscribe asynchronous mechanism. They do not pull data from the server every X minutes. They just listen to incoming data when it is broadcasted. If you want to use MQTT there is an open source project called [`Eclipse Paho`](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/) that you might be interested in.